# FutureTask get vs run, task never finishes

Tags: java, callable, futuretask

I am learning Callables and decided to make a very simple program. The problem is that the Thread is blocked when I call getFutureTask();
Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)

Could you please tell me why is it so and why does my program work when I write futureTask.run() before futureTask.get();
I do understand that get() method waits and returns result. but can't understand what method run() does.
I do appreciate your answers a lot!

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
       FutureTask futureTask = getFutureTask(1);
        System.out.println(futureTask.get());

    }


  public static FutureTask<Integer> getFutureTask(Integer i) {
        return new FutureTask<Integer>(() -> i*45);

    }
```

Comment: `run` is the method that actually starts execution of the task. It is supposed to be called in a different thread, for example by an `ExecutorService`. `get` will not trigger execution, it just waits until the task is done, which happens at the end of `run()`. `FutureTask` is not really supposed to be used directly by an user. Instead you should look into `ExecutorService` and `CompletableFuture` for a nice interface to spawn async tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [`run`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/RunnableFuture.html#run()) vs [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

`run` is the method that actually **starts the execution** of the task. It is supposed to be called in a **different thread**, for example by an `ExecutorService`.

`get` will **not trigger execution**, it just waits until the task is done, i.e. until `run` is finished. This obviously implies that you call `run` somehow before or from a different thread.

---

### [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

`FutureTask` is not really supposed to be used directly by a user. It is more the type of class that is used behind the curtain in order to realize a nice async-API. More specifically, it is the base implementation for `Future`, as for example returned by `ExecutorService` when you spawn tasks with it.

Instead you should look into `ExecutorService`

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
...
Future<Integer> task = service.submit(() -> i * 45);
...
Integer result = task.get();
```

and `CompletableFuture`

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> task = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync​(() -> i * 45);
...
Integer result = task.get();
```

for an easy to use interface to spawn async tasks.

`CompletableFuture`s have the advantage that you can also setup a pipeline of operations that are all executed asynchronously once the previous operation has finished. So for example:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> task = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Foo::readSomeFile)
    .thenApplyAsync(Foo::validateData)
    .thenApplyAsync(Foo::compressData)
    .thenAcceptAsync(Foo::uploadData);
```

Answer (score 3):

From the API of `FutureTask`:

> get() - Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then
> retrieves its result.
>
> run() - Sets this Future to the result of its computation unless it
> has been cancelled.

As such, `run()` will actually run your FutureTask and eventually arrive at a computation result. `get()` on the other Hand gives you the result, if the computation finished. **But** it doesn't start the computation and doesn't call `run()` itself.

See also @Zabuzard's comment:

> run is the method that actually starts execution of the task. It is
> supposed to be called in a different thread, for example by an
> ExecutorService. get will not trigger execution, it just waits until
> the task is done, which happens at the end of run(). FutureTask is not
> really supposed to be used directly by an user. Instead you should
> look into ExecutorService and CompletableFuture for a nice interface
> to spawn async tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `() -> i*45` is just a callable. It is not really executed unless you really start the execution.
And that's exactly what `run()` is for.

So unless you don't explicitly start your thread, nothing of the FutureTask is called.
And `get()` is designed to wait until a thread is finished.
So, normally, you're starting a task (using `run()`), do some other stuff and later get the result using `get()` or wait there, if the task takes more time than expected.

you could check that, e.g. by running some System.out:

```
 public static FutureTask<Integer> getFutureTask(Integer i) {
    return new FutureTask<Integer>(() -> {
        System.out.println("Task started");
        return i * 45;
    });
}
```

you won't see the anything